# Focus on Control

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I want to create `UserControl` of connection to `mdf` file so I want to create new property.

I try that but the problem is every 2 second it ask me to chooseFile...
How I can do only when he try to change the value Or If I can do the property with `"^"` button it will be helpful.

edit:
i used Enum

look that:

```
public enum TypeOfData
{
    NotChoseYet=1,
    ChooseDataBase=2,
    ThereAlreadyDataBase=3
}

public partial class Adodc : UserControl
{
    private bool istart;
    private string sql;
    OpenFileDialog DB = new OpenFileDialog();

    private string DbLocation;

    private TypeOfData? DBchose = (TypeOfData)1;

    public TypeOfData? DataBase
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.DBchose; 
        }
        set 
        {
            if ((int)value == 2) 
            { 
                DB.ShowDialog();
                if (DB.FileName.Length != 0)
                {

                    DbLocation = DB.FileName;
                    DBchose = (TypeOfData)(3);

                }
                     if (DesignMode)
                    {
                        this.Focus();
                    }

            } 
        }
    }

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public  string Location 
    {
        get
        {
            return DbLocation;
        }
    }
}
```

i have one problem after choose DataBase is LostFocus (in the desinger) from the controller i created to the form
it change focus to Form
how i can keep Focus on the UserController

i try added it: but not worked

```
if (DesignMode)
{
    this.Focus();
}
```

maybe there another way to put it focus back

when i choose option 2, the openDialog Opened and i choose file
after i click Ok , the focus set on Form and not back on the controller.

Comment: " every 2 second it ask me to chooseFile" probably because you've put the `ShowDialog` in the get accessor, so every time you try to get the property a dialog is shown.  Rethink your design.

Comment: so how i can do it that it open dialog when i wanna set new file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get
{
    if (dbLocation == null)
    {
        dbDialog.ShowDialog();
        dbLocation = db.FileName;
    }
    return dbLocation;
}
```

Comment: that very good but i can do it when the user Click on button in the Property???
i mean in the Designer the user have to click on the button there
and then the show up??

Comment: @onemore: You need to call the getter from button's click event, the dialog will appear once.

Comment: I don't think there is a way. Because design-time has different purpose. Don't code for it. It's static and not supposed to run much code, especially your own, only infrastructure.